# Open Source MS Word Password Recovery?

Tags: open-source, password-recovery, microsoft-office

Does anyone know of a free open source recovery tool?  Should include recovery of document protection password ideally.

**EDIT:**
I'll settle for just Free instead of free and open source :)  I'm looking for something that will handle not only passwords used to open the file but also passwords used to do Word's different forms of document protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Document form protection is a lot easier to break than document opening protection. Simply open Microsoft Script Editor and replace the contents of the UnprotectPassword value with nothing.

I'm on a Linux box at the moment, so I can't write you a step-by-step, but [this page](http://www.gmayor.com/Remove_Password.htm) looks pretty clear. If you have any problems, leave me a comment and I'll help you out next time I'm using a Windows machine.

Comment: Perfect!  That did exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[This one](http://www.freewordexcelpassword.com/) is free, although not open source.

Comment: Sorry for the delay!  I had played with that one already.  Seems to only work on passwords used to restrict opening the file and not document protection passwords (used for form editing, style changes, etc).  Thanks, though!